# Singular quadrics, covariants of binary quartics and $\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbbk)$ representation

Tags: representation-theory, invariant-theory

Consider the space of irreducible $\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbbk)$ representation:  $$R_4 = \langle x^4, x^3y, x^2y^2,xy^3, y^4 \rangle.$$ This is a 5 dimensional vector space, and we have decomposition for quadrics in this space: $$S^2(R_4) = R_8\oplus R_4 \oplus R_0.$$
There are some singular quadrics. How one can define by the element $(f_8,f_4,f_0)$ that corresponding quadri is singular. I think this could be connected with covariants of binary forms, but I don't know where to start. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: One can certainly write the determinant of the quadratic as a nonhomogeneous linear combination of joint invariants of the $f$'s, but the computation looks quite tedious to me. It can be done using the techniques in section 2 of my article https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1734 The quadratic is represented by a tensor like $B$ on page 20, then one inserts identity (12) same page, five times. For the determinant, the best is probably to write it in terms of traces. This is similar to Gordan's computation mentioned on pages 25, 26.

Comment: A better version of my article, is the one published in JKTR https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218216511009522

Comment: @Abdelmalek Abdesselam thank you!

Comment: I'll try to look into it if I can find the time. In the meantime, you could try your hand on computationally simpler analogous questions for say $S^2(R_3)$ in terms of $f_6,f_2$, or $S^2(R_2)$ in terms of $f_4,f_0$ just for practice.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thanks. Yes, I'll try to deal with easier cases.

Comment: Perhaps even the silly case $S^2(R_1)$ in terms of $f_2$ might be worth looking into.